# grunt-sass multiple src/dest on same structure

Tags: sass, gruntjs

I'm working on a multi-website project where all the website share the same structure:

```
-sites
  -site1
    -css
      -scss
  -site2
    -css
      -scss
```

In my gruntfile.js i have my sass task wrote this way:

```
    sass: {
        options: {
            sourceMap: true,
            outputStyle: 'compressed'
        },
        pippo: {
            files: {
                'sites/site1/css/main.css': 'sites/site1/css/sass/main.scss',
                'sites/site2/css/main.css': 'sites/site2/css/sass/main.scss',
            }
        }
    }
```

is it possible to write it in this way?

```
        sass: {
        options: {
            sourceMap: true,
            outputStyle: 'compressed'
        },
        pippo: {
            files: {
                'sites/**/css/main.css': 'sites/**/css/sass/main.scss'
            }
        }
    }
```

I tested it and it is adding a new ** folder when I build it... Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a couple of hours I found a working solution, at the very top of the grunt file I added:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    console.log("Inside the gruntfile");

    //create dynamic list of scss file paths
    var objDestSource = {
        'public/css/main.css': 'public/css/sass/main.scss'
    };
    fs.readdirSync('sites').forEach(function(folder){
        objDestSource['sites/'+folder+'/css/main.css'] = 'sites/'+folder+'/css/sass/main.scss';
    });
    console.log(objDestSource);
    // end scss function
```

while in the grunt sass task I just changed to:

```
sass: {
        options: {
            sourceMap: true,
            outputStyle: 'compressed'
        },
        taskName: {
            files: objDestSource
        }
    }
```

and the watch task:

```
watch: {
   sass: {
       files: [
           'public/css/sass/**/*.scss',
           'sites/**/css/sass/**/*.scss'
       ],
       tasks: ['sass'],
       options: {
           spawn: false
       }
   }
}
```

This way I can add a new sub-website without have to edit the gruntfile each time!